# CRM 2013: Add item under gear menu

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm looking for a way to add a link to the Upper right hand gear menu in CRM 2013, but I'm not able to find a way to configure this. Here is an image of the drop down menu I'm trying to add things to

[image: This is the gear menu I'm talking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in a supported manner.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  I asked on the dynamics forum as well, and they gave the same answer.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/152863.aspx